# wordpress domine mapping subdomine noindex htaccess robots.txt

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mapping, robots.txt

I have a WP-Multisite and different sites ... of course :P

To register a new site in my multisite I create a subdomain type:

```
siteNew1.mydominemultisite.com
siteNew2.mydominemultisite.com
siteNewN.mydominemultisite.com
```

I only have one main directory (only one database)

Then with the WordPress Plugin MU Domain Mapping (https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/
) and I do this mapping:

```
siteNew1.mydominemultisite.com → www.dominecustomer.com
```

All perfect !!!! but ....

Google is indexed siteNew1.mydominemultisite.com and this URL must be completely hidden for Google and users.

As Google does not index the content of siteNew1.mydominemultisite.com and the other pages?

I think this can be done from `htaccess` or `robots.txt` but it should do a non-index only of:

```
http://siteNew1.mydominemultisite.com/*
http://siteNew2.mydominemultisite.com/*
http://siteNewN.mydominemultisite.com/*
```

Answer (score 0):

With >> Google Search Console << you can remove the indexing of the content.

And in theory it has not appeared again